# Использование strftime вместе с LIKE

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3, datetime

Интересует заголовок вопроса. Будет ли функция **sqlite** работать в **LIKE**?

Ниже пример кода, который у меня почему-то не хочет работать. Жалуется на синтаксическую ошибку в формате даты: **'%-d.%-m.%Y'**.

Полный код ошибки: **SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

```
SELECT COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_DATE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL_DATE LIKE strftime('%-d.%-m.%Y', 'now')
```

Помогите советом, пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробуйте так: `'%d.%m.%Y'`

Comment: @MaxU
Пробовал. То же самое - синтаксическая ошибка. И мне надо  месяц и день выбирать без первых нулей в числе

Comment: `SyntaxError` говорит, что у вас проблема в Питон коде. Создайте минимальный пример кода, который к ошибке ведёт и добавьте его в вопрос вместе с полным traceback. Скорее всего кавычки правильного типа для строковой константы нужно использовать¶ Независимо от предыдущей ошибки, не похоже что `%-d` поддерживается,
 только `%d`: [пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ba72c8/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlite не поддерживает `%-d` синтаксис (`-` значит: без ведущих нулей число). Можно в Питоне строку отформатировать на некоторых системах, используя без изменений формат:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import datetime as DT
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
db.execute("create table dates (d date)")
db.execute("insert into dates values('7.3.2018')")
print(db.execute('select * from dates where d like ?',
                 (DT.date.today().strftime('%-d.%-m.%Y'),)).fetchone()[0])
```

[Результат](https://ideone.com/W5E3tp):

```
7.3.2018
```

Если код может запускаться на платформе, где `%-d` не поддерживается, можно руками в Питоне отформатировать:

```
>>> "{d.day}.{d.month}.{d.year}".format(d=DT.date.today())
'7.3.2018'
```

Предпочтительно, `%Y-%m-%d` формат для даты использовать (сортировка, значения по умолчанию).